# which trig identities are used here?

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone help me with the intermediate steps here please, because they have been left out of the textbook and I am unsure.

so we have this equation:

$\sqrt{1-e}\tan\frac{\theta - \theta_{0}}{2} = \sqrt{1+e}\tan\frac{\eta}{2}$

and taking t=0 to occur at the pericentre passage $r_1 = a(1-e)$ and from $L=r^2 \dot{\theta}$ we have

$t = \int_{\theta_{0}}^{\theta} \frac{d\theta}{\dot{\theta}} = \int d\theta \frac{r^2}{L} = \frac{a^2}{L} \int_{0}^{\eta} d\eta \frac{d\theta}{d\eta} (1-e\cos\eta)^2$

evaluating $\frac{d\theta}{d\eta}$  from the first equation, integrating and using trigonometric identities to simplify the result, we obtain

$t = \frac{a^2}{L} \sqrt{1-e^2} (\eta - e\sin\eta) = \frac{T_{r}}{2\pi}(\eta - e\sin\eta)$

where the 2nd identity follows because the bracket on the right increases by $2\pi$ over an orbital period.

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: There is no t in your first equation so taking t = 0 brings any reader of this problem to a stop.

Comment: @Paul I think that maybe they ordered it oddly, and I've to integrate first and the t dependence comes from the angular momentum equation? unsure though

Comment: @Paul - the $t$ comes in the equation $L = r^2\dot \theta$, where it is the variable the differentiation is with respect to.

Comment: @PaulSinclair yeah that's what I was thinking! any ideas on the rest of the working? still pretty stuck

Comment: SFL: If you find an answer helpful, you can (1) upvote the answer.  If you find one answer the most helpful, you can (1) upvote the answer, and you can also *accept* the answer.  To accept an answer, simply click on the grey arrow to the left of the answer you'd like to accept.   When you click on it, it turns green.  And you get 2 pts. for every accepted answer.  The answerer of the accepted answer is also awarded points, in addition to the points awarded for upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Parts of this come from information you have not reproduced, so I can't really say for sure. It is evidently related to orbital equations, and I haven't looked at those in many years. I have no idea what "at the pericentre passage" even means. However, this is what I can figure out.

Obviously $$t = \int_0^tdt = \int_{\theta_0}^\theta \frac{dt}{d\theta}d\theta = \int_{\theta_0}^\theta \frac{d\theta}{\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)} = \int_{\theta_0}^\theta\frac{d\theta}{\dot\theta}$$
Now make the substitution $\dot \theta = L /r^2$ and then a second substitution for $r = a(1-e\cos\eta)$, an equation that does not follow from anything you've written here, but is evidently a formula for an elliptical orbit (or more general conic section). I'm not sure that $\eta$ is, but apparently, $\eta = 0$ at the "pericentre passage", since the lower limit of the integral (which still corresponds to $t = 0$) is $0$.

$$t = \int_{\theta_0}^\theta\frac{r^2}L\, d\theta=\frac{a^2}L\int_{0}^{\eta}  (1-e\cos\eta)^2\frac{d\theta}{d\eta}\,d\eta$$

To determine $\frac{d\theta}{d\eta}$, we need to differentiate the formula you gave. To make it less messy, let $\alpha = \frac{\theta - \theta_0}2, \beta = \frac\eta2, A = \sqrt{1-e}, B = \sqrt{1+e}$. It is easy to confirm that $\frac{d\theta}{d\eta}=\frac{d\alpha}{d\beta}$. So
$$A\tan\alpha = B\tan\beta\\A\left(\sec^2\alpha\right) \frac{d\alpha}{d\beta} = B\sec^2\beta\\A\left(1 + \tan^2\alpha\right)\frac{d\alpha}{d\beta} = B\left(1 + \tan^2\beta\right)\\\left(A^2 + A^2\tan^2\alpha\right) \frac{d\alpha}{d\beta}= AB\left(1+\tan^2\beta\right)\\\left(A^2 + B^2\tan^2\beta\right) \frac{d\alpha}{d\beta}= AB\left(1+\tan^2\beta\right)\\\frac{d\alpha}{d\beta} = \frac{AB\left(1+\tan^2\beta\right)}{A^2 + B^2\tan^2\beta}$$
Substitute back in the original values, we get
$$\frac{d\theta}{d\eta} = \frac{\sqrt{1 - e^2}\left(1+\tan^2\frac\eta2\right)}{\left(1+\tan^2\frac\eta2\right) - e^2 + e^2\tan^2\frac\eta2}$$
So
$$t = \frac{a^2}L\int_{0}^{\eta}  (1-e\cos\eta)^2\frac{\sqrt{1 - e^2}\left(1+\tan^2\frac\eta2\right)}{\left(1+\tan^2\frac\eta2\right) - e^2 + e^2\tan^2\frac\eta2}\,d\eta$$

A horrid mess, but there are a couple of potential approaches: make one or both of the substitutions $$\tan\frac\eta2 = \frac{\sin \eta}{1 - \cos\eta} = \frac{1 + \cos\eta}{\sin\eta}$$ or make the substitution $$u = \tan\frac\eta2,\quad \cos\eta = \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}, \quad d\eta = \frac{2du}{1+u^2}$$

I've not explored which gives a more useful result yet, but I suspect that one or the other will produce something that can be integrated.